# How to add left drawable in Spinner View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Hello I am trying to add left drawable in `Spinner` but I didn't find any propery for this as you do same in `EditText` using `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_drawable"`. Is there any correct way to achieve same in `Spinner` in Android.

Here in my case there should be left drawable only this state which I gave in the screenshot, when user click on the Spinner I don't want to have left drawable there in open drop down list in `Spinner`

I'm trying like this where there is no such attribute

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/selectSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_views_vertical_top_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
     />
```

I want something like below screenshot

[image]

Currently it is looking like below

[image]

and when I set the background of the `Spinner` then it looks like

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/selectSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_views_vertical_top_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/selectone_drawable"
    android:entries="@array/select_type" />
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can set the background for the spinner.

android:background="@drawable/your_drawable"

Comment: @Sripathi It didn't work, setting background is not a way IMO because it set this background image on complete spinner

Comment: Now you are setting the arrow block alone as background right(the box contains a down arrow)?
Use nine-patch, else you can change your png image as a box(like edittext) having a square at the left end(the spinner layout you want).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a nine-patch image and set it as the background of the Spinner, then add a left padding, should do the trick.

Comment: No, it did not work for me, see my updated question I added the screenshot

Comment: Create a nine-patch image and set it as background. Then it should work.

Comment: Will do it for you when I get home, can't do it at work right now. Or you could try doing it yourself by doing some research about nine-patch images, it is really useful in any Android project :)

Comment: The great thing is that you can give the spinner any width without stretching the image.

Comment: yeah that is advantage of nine patch drawables, nice concept

Answer (score 17):

create a xml drawable @drawable/gradient_spinner
 `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="@color/myTextPrimaryColor" android:startColor="@color/myTextPrimaryColor" android:type="linear" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/bg_eo" />

            <corners android:radius="4dp" />

            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape></item>
        <item ><bitmap android:gravity="right|center" android:src="@drawable/expnd" />
        </item>
    </layer-list></item>

</selector> `
```

set spinner background android:background="@drawable/gradient_spinner"

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, after changing gravity to `left|center`. :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: layout looks like this]

dummy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list android:opacity="transparent">
            <item android:width="100dp" android:end="300dp" android:gravity="left">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#269cf7">

                    </solid>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:width="300dp" android:gravity="right" android:start="100dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/transparent">

                    </solid>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:width="100dp" android:end="300dp">
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/arrow_bottom" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In the layout file add this code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <Spinner
        android:background="@drawable/dummy"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thank you.. This works perfectly. I dont know why above correct answer wrote 9 patch file??

Comment: Someone need to mention ta you need to use png not vector drawables for the above dummy.xml.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           if(view!=null) {
               ((TextView) view).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);//remove extra padding
               ((TextView)view) .setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_image), null, null, null);
               ((TextView) view).setCompoundDrawablePadding(20);// to set drawablePadding
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Said, you should put the following image as a background of the spinner and take required left padding so that the text will be right after the arrow image.

[image]

Following is some code to make you understand more ;)

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/selectSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_views_vertical_top_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/the_attached_drawable"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/required_padding_for_each_screen_size"
    android:entries="@array/select_type" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/white"></solid>

                    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_drop_down_icon" android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />

        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

For example [image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to create a `LinearLayout` wrapping `spinner` then change the `LinearLayout` the way you want, for example, use `ImageView` and `Spinner` in a Horizontal Layout. This way user will see a `Spinner` with a image in the left side.

I achieve it this way only. Easy and best solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

spinner_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftDrawable"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.your_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<string-array name="your_array">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <!-- Add more items as needed -->
</string-array>
```